# Include once ob_get_contents undefined variables

Tags: php, include, ob-get-contents

In my admin.php I set my `$controller` and it works great as a dynamic CMS, the problem I have is the files that I am using as templates don't recognize `$controller` in them.

**Admin.php**

```
include_once("configuration.php");
require("cms.php");
$controller = new CMS();
...
$controller->template("body");
```

**Cms.php**

```
Class CMS{
   /*New template function*/
   function template($file){
      if( isset($file) && file_exists($file.".php") ){
         include_once($file.".php");
      }else{
         echo "";
      }
    }

  /*Old template function*/
  function template($file){
     if(isset($file) && file_exists($file.".php")){
        ob_start();
        include($file.".php");
        $template = ob_get_contents();
        return $template;
       } else {
         echo "";
       }
   }

}
```

**Any template page**

```
var_dump($controller);
```

Which echos `Notice: Undefined variable: controller in`

It'll be easier if I can get `$controller` to be accessible without having to call it every time. Am I missing something here why is the `$controller` undefined on any template page?

**UPDATE**

What seemed to work for me is by adding the var again like so

```
Class CMS{
   /*New template function*/
   function template($file){
      if( isset($file) && file_exists($file.".php") ){
         $controller = $this;
         include_once($file.".php");
      }else{
         echo "";
      }
    }
}
```

is that acceptable?

Comment: so basically I should do something like `function instantiate(){ include_once('configuration.php'); require('cms.php'); return global $controller = new CMS(); }` ?

Comment: because I thought when you included a file it would be basically as if that file existed already, and the variables could be passed in without having to redefine them.